# How to restrict access to S3 bucket to traffic coming from my EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vpc, amazon-eks

I need to craft an S3 access policy such that it rejects traffic coming from the internet, except for traffic coming from my EKS cluster.

**Context:**
My EKS cluster is running an application that needs to access S3, but I do not want to allow traffic from any other source. (EKS is an AWS-managed kubernetes service).

Ideally, I would prefer to simply block all traffic from the internet and handle this within a private network (VPC?). But I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Otherwise, I think I will need to simply whitelist the IP address of the EKS nodes, which given the fact that EKS nodes are transient, seems like a cumbersome and un-realistic solution.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Amazon EKS: how to configure S3 access for worker nodes?](https://serverfault.com/a/932146/267968) Basically, **instead of using a Bucket Policy, put the necessary permissions in an IAM Role** that is then assigned to the workers. They will be given credentials that will be automatically accessed by applications running on the node.

Comment: I actually just found a solution, I allowed s3 operations from the VPC endpoint for the VPC that my EKS cluster resides in. However, I am going to look into your solution @JohnRotenstein as it seems like a cleaner solution